# Formatting UTC Date/Time in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an app with ASP.NET MVC. Currently, the users create records. I store the date/time the records were created in UTC time. When I display them to the user, I want to format them like `February 8, 2015 at 9:30 pm (local time)`. How do I do that in my view? Currently, I have:

```
@(Model.CreatedOnUTC.ToLongDateString() + " at " + Model.CreatedOnUTC.ToShortTimeString())
```

However, this isn't quite right.First, its not converting to the user's local time. And second, the format isn't correct. I know the server is not guaranteed to know the user's time zone. Let's assume it does though.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a pretty similar requirement with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

In the view:

```
<div class="utcdate-tolocaldate"> 
    @Html.Raw(Model.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"))
</div>
```

and then with a function:

```
function utcConversion() {
   $('.utcdate-tolocaldate').each(function () {
       $(this).html(moment($(this).text()).format('L, LT'));
   });
   $('.utcdate-tolocaldateNoTime').each(function () {
       $(this).html(moment($(this).text()).format('L'));
   });
}
```

and here is the [link for formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/):

Comment: Why is it in a `td`?

Comment: I just needed an html element, I'll change that to a div